# How to output web page html source code into a file

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, gdb, w3m

My goal is to output an html source into a file, I'm using **w3m** to browse the web from terminal.

When using the following command on terminal: `w3m <url> -dump` the program displays the web site in a non interactive way, but no its html source.

If you open a web site with `w3m <url>`, the terminal will display the site and if you press **v**, then the program will display the html source, I tried to script this but with no success. I thought the command line argument `-dump_source` would help me, but the only thing I got is a non-human reading content, I don't know what `-dump_source` was supposed to return

Here is what I tried so far:

- Use `-T text/html` with `-dump` on terminal but the output didn't changed
- Use `-T text/plain` with `-dump_source` on terminal hoping that the non-human output would be converted to a plain text, but no success (I didn't understand what -T is used for, even after reading w3m manual by typing `man w3m` on terminal)
- Knowing that pressing **v** while w3m is displaying a web site switch from web page content to html source code, I tried to use **gdb** to attach it to the w3m process and redirect its **stdin** and **stdout** to my files (input.txt, output.txt) which input.txt contains a single **v**, but I had no success. Doing this on my test program worked as expected. I followed what was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323956/how-to-redirect-output-of-an-already-running-process?noredirect=1&lq=1). If I write `ls -l /proc/<w3m_pid>/fd`, where w3m_pid is my w3m process id which I got by using `ps ax` on terminal, I can see there is 3 file descriptors, if I try to redirect the third one, the program crashes and displays: **Error occured: errorno=25**
- Redirecting the standard I/O with `w3m <url> < input.txt > output.txt` also did not worked
- W3M uses keybinding to navigate on the web, it means that if you press **v** there is no need to hit enter, the terminal is not buffering the input, using gdb attached to the w3m process I tried to remove it by using `p system ("/bin/stty cooked")`, but the w3m keybind did not changed.

My question is: why redirecting I/O with gdb is not working and what I can do to get html source code? w3m have an option to output html source code that I'm missing or I would have to use another program?

PS: I need html source code for a university homework, with html source code I can create a script to browse the web and output the page into a file, than I'm supposed to use those outputs with flex to extract statics information about things on the web, like: how many the word stack appears in questions about the c language? This is my idea.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**W3M version:** 0.5.3+debian-15

**GDB version:** 7.7.1

**Ubuntu version:** 14.04

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about directly fetching the HTML file from the server using `wget` or `curl`?

Comment: I'll take a look on wget, but curl already helped me, ty for suggestions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why can't you use `curl`?

```
curl web-address > file-source.
```

will output the source code in the `file`

Like this

```
curl http://askubuntu.com/questions/822139/how-to-output-web-page-html-source-code-into-a-file > source-html
```

Comment: Thank you, how could I miss this? maybe I should look more for what I have installed on my machine. Worked as I expected

Comment: @MurilloHenrique that happens :)

Comment: He might want to reuse the w3m cookies.

Answer (score 3):

This has already been answered in: https://askubuntu.com/a/1273410/1124534

```bash
w3m -o accept_encoding=UTF-8 -dump_source google.com >file
```