# w3m charset source_dump not working correctly

Tags: encoding, w3m, character-set

I am trying to use the following command but can't get the right output:

```
$ w3m -dump_source google.com
r���G��2�Ph��ү�f�� ����?�l���%Y:���c(�����������Y\��s8Ư|   ��;����1ʹ��D��^�lK���٥r��\���Սk�V��Ϸv���{��r�����~s\��~?�ML7���¹���ƿ�qm��h��q�(��:wZ a�
```

How can I change the charset?

I've also tried

```
w3m -O "UTF-8" -dump_source "google.com"
```

and

```
w3m -I "UTF-8" -dump_source "google.com"
```

but none worked.

Comment: Try with -O or -I see if it helps.

Comment: I've tried w3m -O "UTF-8" -dump_source "google.com" and w3m -I "UTF-8" -dump_source "google.com" yet, but nothing doesn't work :(

Comment: Do you _need_ to do this with `w3m`? Would ` wget -O - google.com` or `curl www.google.com` be OK?

Comment: Yes. I need to do this with w3m.

Comment: Why do you need `-dump_source`? What is the goal?

Comment: goal is to get source code using w3m)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

month of attempts, but the result with w3m could not be reached.

Alternative option using elinks:

```
elinks -source google.com
```

There was also a problem with the encoding. but it turned out to be solved as follows

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

put it to terminal

Answer (score 2):

```bash
    w3m -o accept_encoding=UTF-8 -dump_source google.com
```

or

```bash
    w3m -o accept_encoding=='*;q=0' -dump_source google.com
```

Comment: This worked for me and still uses w3m, perfect!